# How to construct a homomorphism from an abelian group to $\mathbb{Q}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, abelian-groups, group-homomorphism

For any abelian group $A$. Is it possible to construct a nontrivial homomorphism from $A \to \mathbb{Q}$?

Is it possible if $A$ is a finite generate abelian group?

Comment: No, it is not, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2018257/show-texthom-aba-mathbbq-0-for-finite-a).

Comment: What would your homomorphism do to an element of $A$ of finite order?

Comment: what if $A$ is a finite cyclic group?

Comment: yes,  I think I got it.

Comment: @co-co-nuts You can post an answer to your own question, and accept your own answer. That way the quesiton won't remain on the open queue attracting attention.